# Regex Split certain character outside single/double quote except escape quotes

Tags: regex, split, quote

I am trying to construct a regular expression in Java, which could be used to split the string by a character outside single/double quotes except the escape quotes. For example, if I want to split string by comma:

1) "hello , world"    = ["hello , world"]

2) "hello" , world    = ["hello"][world]

3) "hello \" , world" = ["hello \", world"]

4) hello , \" world   = [hello][\" world]

Note that, I am comparing with the string that is inputted by the user. So, the double quotes and escape double quotes in above example are all inserted by the user and not a string declaration inside my code.

My current expression could only split the string by a character that is outside any single or double quote (which means it will fail example 4 above). It could not ignore the escape quotes entered by the user. Below is the example of expression to split by comma:

```
String delimeter = "[^\\\\]*,(?=([^\"\']*(\"|\')[^\1]*\1)*[^\"\']*$)";
```

Comment: What's wrong with matching instead of splitting?

Comment: Hi Avinash, I don't really understand your suggestions. I am not matching because I still have to split eventually.

Comment: Try `(?s),(?=(?:((?<!\\)["'])(?:(?!(?<!\\)\1).)*(?<!\\)\1|\\.|[^"'])*$)` ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wC2xT6/1), [regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/7b7vm) click on "Java" / as Java String)

Comment: Wow! That works. I will run a thorough test to see if it meet the overall condition. Thanks alot Jonny

Comment: @Jonny5 Great one! It should be posted as an answer!